# Chrome Extension - How to send data to it and open popup window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

My company has an internal version of ChatGPT that we use, and I was working on creating an extension to have a better way to interact with it.

Basically, we have an internal site, that has a chatbot very similar to the OpenAI one.

As of now, I created an extension that allows me to select editable text in Chrome, and when I right click, I have a list of prompts.
If I click on one, it opens a new tab with the chatbot, and pastes the prompt + selected text.

That works fine.

Also, I have a popup window, when I click on the extension icon, that loads that same site in the popup window.

What I want is to select text, right click on it and select a prompt, and instead of jumping into a new tab with the site, just open the popup window and paste the prompt+text in there.

What I have so far:

My manifest.json file has:

```
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_title": "Chatbot Helper",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://internal.chatbot.com/*"],
      "js": ["content.js","popup.js"],
    }
```

My popup.js is just:

```
"use strict";
```

But my popup.html is:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="module" src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe src="https://internal.chatbot.com/" frameborder="0" style="width: 600px;height:580px;"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

In my background.js, this is the part that takes the selected text to the new tab:

```
    const selectedItem = menuItems[info.menuItemId];
    if (selectedItem) {
        savedText(selectedMenuItem + " \n" + info.selectionText);
        newTab(chatbotURL);
    }
```

Also, is there a way to invoke that popup by hitting a combination of keys? Instead of clicking on it?

I tried this because I saw a post with something similar but no luck:

```
    const selectedItem = menuItems[info.menuItemId];
    if (selectedItem) {
        savedText(selectedMenuItem + " \n" + info.selectionText);
        chrome.tabs.create({url:"https://internal.chatbot.com/"});
    }
```